# How to refresh/reload datagrid in WPF?

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, xaml

I want to implement a datagrid, which will be filled every 5min.

But, first code: 
XAML:

```
    <Window.Resources>
    <ObjectDataProvider x:Key="_employeeProvider" ObjectType="{x:Type Brw1:EmployeeDataProvider}" />
    <ObjectDataProvider x:Key="_employeeFactory" ObjectInstance="{StaticResource _employeeProvider}" MethodName="GetEmployees" />
</Window.Resources>

<Grid DataContext="{Binding Source={StaticResource _employeeFactory}}">
    <DataGrid Name="_employeeDataGrid" DockPanel.Dock="Top" Margin="12,57,12,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" ItemsSource="{Binding}" AutoGenerateColumns="True">
    </DataGrid>
</Grid>
```

C#:

```
    public class EmployeeDataProvider
{
    public ObservableEmployee GetEmployees()
    {
        // This is only example
        // In my project right here I will get data from database, put into the list, and fill datagrid with it. 
        List<UIEmployee> list = new List<UIEmployee>
                {
                    new UIEmployee { Id = 1, FirstName = "Prajeesh2", LastName = "Prathap", Occupation = "Engineer", DateOfJoining=new DateTime(2005, 8, 1), IsContracter = false, AddressInfo = null },
                    new UIEmployee { Id = 2, FirstName = "Rahul2", LastName = "Bose", Occupation = "Student", DateOfJoining=new DateTime(2009, 5, 4), IsContracter = true, AddressInfo = null },
                    new UIEmployee { Id = 3, FirstName = "Steve2", LastName = "Roberts", Occupation = "Manager", DateOfJoining=new DateTime(1994, 8, 23), IsContracter = false, AddressInfo = null },
                    new UIEmployee { Id = 4, FirstName = "Micheal2", LastName = "Clarke", Occupation = "Engineer", DateOfJoining=new DateTime(2003, 1, 14), IsContracter = true, AddressInfo = null },
                    new UIEmployee { Id = 5, FirstName = "Rachel2", LastName = "Green", Occupation = "Professional", DateOfJoining=new DateTime(2006, 3, 8), IsContracter = true, AddressInfo = null }
                };

        ObservableEmployee employeeCollection = new ObservableEmployee(list);
        return employeeCollection;
    }
}
```

It is very simple. Datagrid use `GetEmployees()` method to get data.

What I try to do, is to run GetEmployess every 5min..

PS. `_employeeDataGrid.Items.Refresh();` - doesn't work.

UPDATE:

Missing classes:

```
    public class ObservableEmployee : ObservableCollection<UIEmployee>
{
    public ObservableEmployee(IEnumerable<UIEmployee> employees) : base(employees) { }
}

public class UIEmployee// : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    private int m_Id;
    public int Id
    {
        get { return m_Id; }
        set
        {
            m_Id = value;
        }
    }

    private string m_FirstName;
    public string FirstName
    {
        get { return m_FirstName; }
        set
        {
            m_FirstName = value;
        }
    }

    private string m_LastName;
    public string LastName
    {
        get { return m_LastName; }
        set
        {
            m_LastName = value;
        }
    }

    private string m_Occupation;
    public string Occupation
    {
        get { return m_Occupation; }
        set
        {
            m_Occupation = value;
        }
    }

    private DateTime m_DateOfJoining;
    public DateTime DateOfJoining
    {
        get { return m_DateOfJoining; }
        set
        {
            m_DateOfJoining = value;
        }
    }

    private bool m_IsContracter;
    public bool IsContracter
    {
        get { return m_IsContracter; }
        set
        {
            m_IsContracter = value;
        }
    }

}
```

UPDATE2: 
I need something, that will reload datagrid, so datagrid will have to use `GetEmployees` method again.

**UPDATE3:**

```
public class TaskDataProvider
{
    static ObservableEmployee list = new ObservableEmployee();
    static DataRepository dr = new DataRepository();

    public static ObservableEmployee GetEmployees()
    {
        UpdateMyList();
        return list;
    }

    public static void UpdateMyList() 
    {
        ObservableTask newList = new ObservableTask(dr.GetTasks());

        list.Clear();
        foreach (Task t in newList)
        {
            list.Add(t);
        }
    }
}
```

This at start works. 
But that, I change sth in database, and click the button which do:

```
TaskDataProvider.UpdateMyList();
```

And on  break point, it's gets right data (new data) - but, datagrid is not refreshing:/

Comment: can you, please, post a code where you actually assign to DataContext the collection got from GetEmployees() ?

Comment: I did. That's all. Only missing code are two methods: 
UIEmployee and ObservableEmployee. 

Datagrid use DataContext of parent Grid, so "_employeeFactory" and this class use method "GetEmployees" which returns ObservableEmployee. There are no more code.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Or, you could just null `ItemsSource` out and initialised it again:

```
dataGridView.ItemsSource = null;
dataGridView.ItemsSource = ItemsSourceObjects;
```

Answer (score 12):

dataGrid1.Items.refresh();

to update the contents of DataGrid

Answer (score 1):

I gues this cause binding is not aware that you changed collection. 
I would suggest, or:

- Clear and after populate a collection previously binded to grid with a new data (the same collection, as in `GetEmployees()` you every time create a new one.

or

- Before assigning new collection *try* to assign to DataContext `null` or an empty collection and after actually assign a new one.

or

**EDIT**

```
 ObservableEmployee <UIEmployee> list = new ObservableEmployee <UIEmployee>(); //move list to global variables and declare it as ObservableCollection
 public ObservableEmployee GetEmployees()
    {

       //here only return an instance of list
       return list;

    }

//this method call when you want to update data on gri
public void UpdateMyList() {

     //clear list 
     list.Clear();

     //after add all data
     list.Ad(..);
     list(..); 
     .
     .

}
```

- Use `UpdateTarget` like provided in folowing example: [DataBinding Refresh in WPF](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/forums/en-us/wpf/thread/67BEA8F4-8DA8-473D-B20A-A646DC5EE963)

Comment: I'm sorry, but I don't know how, in case of first two suggests.
And third, I read whole topic, but still can't deal with that problem. I started with WPF only few days ago.. 
Could you help me, and show this on my code?

Comment: if after every 5 second you need to update content of the DataGrid, try to not every time create new list in GetEmployees() method. But instance one global, and inside that method refresh the list with the new data after every 5 secs.

Comment: Hi, thx for replay.
But my problem is that I don't know how to refresh the list :/
I have breakpoint inside "GetEmployees" method, and during debugging it only stops there once (at the beginning). 
Than I call "_employeeDataGrid.Items.Refresh();" and "GetEmployees" isn't called.

Comment: @Marshall: see my edited post. List is declared like ObservableCollection, in GetEmployess it return just the same list and doesn't create a new one every time, and there is a method for updating a content of the list. So considering the fact that list is ObservableCollection and its binded to grid, in irdr to update grdi content, you need only change list data, everythign else will be done by WPF binding mechanism.

Comment: ^^ I'm not sure about that solution. Look at my Update3.

Comment: @Marshal in your update you again create a new list. Try to wark directly on (list) global variable instead. Clear its content and after ADD new elements and NOT assign new list

Comment: Thank you! it works like a charm. The final solution is in my Update3. Thanks:)

Comment: @Marshall: it's not a sharm, it's a DataBinding :) Good luck

Comment: [@Tigran]Hi,Can you just give the reason for your second point
(Before assigning new collection try to assign to DataContext null or an empty collection and after actually assign a new one.)
i'm just blindly doing that without knowing the reason thats why i asked,
thanks

Comment: @PintuPaul: _try_ to reset databinding. Databinding saves internaly a pointer to a datastructure you assigned first, by setting to nul you _may_ to rest it so new assignment may take effect desired.