# wpf datagrid resort bug

Tags: wpf, datagrid, collectionview

I am stuck here for 3 weeks now, I am dying :-)

When I refresh my collection, the SortDescription does not work. This is a know bug in wpf I read on the internet.

But I can't seem to get it working... My experience isn't that far it seems :-)
Can someone help me out please and SHOW me how to re-sort my datagrid...

xaml:

```
<XmlDataProvider x:Key="SmsData" XPath="/response/conv/sms" >

    </XmlDataProvider>

    <local:RowColorConverter x:Key="RowColorConverter" />

    <CollectionViewSource x:Key="SmsView"  Source="{StaticResource SmsData}" >
        <CollectionViewSource.SortDescriptions>
            <scm:SortDescription PropertyName="date" Direction="Descending" />
            <scm:SortDescription PropertyName="time" Direction="Descending" />

        </CollectionViewSource.SortDescriptions>

        <CollectionViewSource.GroupDescriptions>
            <dat:PropertyGroupDescription PropertyName="recipient" />

        </CollectionViewSource.GroupDescriptions>
    </CollectionViewSource>


   ...

   <DataGrid  ItemsSource="{Binding}" DataContext="{StaticResource SmsView}"   Name="dataGrid1">

    ...
```

I am binding dataprovider by code, it's an xml file that I'm getting from internet url.

cs:

```
     public void makeConnection()
{

            ...

            XmlDocument doc = new XmlDocument();
            doc.Load(readStream);

            //refreshing my data
            xdp = FindResource("SmsData") as XmlDataProvider;
            xdp.Document = doc;

            //re-sort => this not working
            if (dataGrid1.ItemsSource != null)
            {

               CollectionViewSource cvs = FindResource("SmsView") as CollectionViewSource;

               cvs.GroupDescriptions.Clear();
               cvs.GroupDescriptions.Add(new PropertyGroupDescription("recipient"));
               cvs.SortDescriptions.Clear();
               cvs.SortDescriptions.Add(new SortDescription("date",ListSortDirection.Descending));
       cvs.SortDescriptions.Add(new SortDescription("time",ListSortDirection.Descending));
               cvs.View.Refresh();
                 }

}
```

Comment: Are you sure that the code inside the if (dataGrid1.ItemsSource != null) {...} is being reached? If the ItemsSource isn't already set for the grid, it will never get refreshed. Sorry not to post it as an answer, but I don't have the code for the "dataGrid1" (please post it too). Let me know if this helps, regards

Comment: yes, the code is being reached, because I tried with messagebox and it shows up if I refresh :-) I updated my post with the code for dataGrid1

Comment: It's kind of a long shot, but everything is worth a try when you are stuck: in your C# code create a ListCollectionView and populate it with the xml document. Make the ListCollectionView public and give it get and set accesors, and then bind the DataGrid with ItemsSource="{Binding SmsListCollectionView}". Once I used a CollectionViewSource and the GetDefaultView method returned a view which was not sortable. I switched everything to ListCollectionView and I had no problem ever since.

Comment: Hi ! I tried to implement this morning. And this solution worked !! But.. to refresh I do, dataContext = null and then recall my collection into dataContext. Isn't this a bad way ? Because that way, I remake the whole datagrid each refresh...

Comment: In my humble opinion it's not bad to set the datacontext to null and then again to the ListCollectionView (although the ListCollectionView should notify the grid of changes in the collection...). If you don't mind, I'll post my previous comment as an answer so you can approve it, ok?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your C# code create a ListCollectionView and populate it with the xml document. Make the ListCollectionView public and give it get and set accesors, and then bind the DataGrid with ItemsSource="{Binding SmsListCollectionView}". Once I used a CollectionViewSource and the GetDefaultView method returned a view which was not sortable. I switched everything to ListCollectionView and I had no problem ever since.

Regarding the refresh, I think you are OK, [see this SO question and its solution.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7215409/how-to-refresh-reload-datagrid-in-wpf)