# Reloading/replacing a new table into WPF DataGrid at runtime

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, mvvm, datagrid

I've been trying to essentially replace the whole table that is auto generated by the DataGrid control with a new DataTable.

I looked at [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7215409/how-to-refresh-reload-datagrid-in-wpf) before, but I've been trying to avoid referencing UI elements in my viewmodel class (or adding code to the Mainwindow.xaml.cs as a last resort).

First I bound the ItemsSource for a DataGrid to a DataView property I have in my Viewmodel:

```
<DataGrid Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column ="1" ItemsSource="{Binding DisplayView}"/>

private DataView displayView;

public DataView DisplayView
{
    get { return displayView; }
    set { displayView = value; }
}
```

I also have a method that formats an SQL table into an appropriate DataTable, which I then assign to the DataView bound to the grid.

```
DisplayView = dtCloned.DefaultView;
```

When I call this method in the constructor, the table fills up on execution.

Calling it during runtime creates a new table in the same format, but assigning it to the DataView property doesn't reload the DataGrid to show the new table; where am I going wrong?

Comment: Your view-model need to implement `INotifyPropertyChanged` and notify changes for the `DisplayView` property.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For bindings to be aware of any updates on the properties behind you must implement the INotifyPropertyChanged interface on your viewmodel/model.

Once you do so, your code should look like this:

```
public class YourViewModel : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    ...

    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

    private DataView displayView;
    public DataView DisplayView
    {
        get { return displayView; }
        set 
        {    
            displayView = value;

            if (PropertyChanged != null)
            {                
                PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(nameof(DisplayView)));
            }
        }
    }

    ...
}
```

More information on the interface found [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.inotifypropertychanged(v=vs.110).aspx).

Comment: Thank you, it's exactly what I needed. :)